# Returning NSTextView's Selection Attributes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

[image]

When you use **TextEdit** and have a selection of string, it will give you the selection color, font, size and other attributes as you see above.  How do you get those text selection attributes?  I'm certain that I need to use the selectedTextAttributes method.  I have the following lines of code.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification object] == textView1) {
        ...
        ...
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[textView1 selectedTextAttributes] mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    }
}
```

If I run it, the result is not quite like what I expect.

```
NSBackgroundColor = "NSNamedColorSpace System selectedTextBackgroundColor";
NSColor = "NSNamedColorSpace System selectedTextColor";
```

There aren't really useful values that I can use to get the text color of the string selection and other attributes.  If I ask Google about selectedTextColor, I don't get much luck.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like good values - NSColor, not sure why do you think it's not useful, what do you need that color for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectedTextAttributes describe what the selection highlighting looks like, not the attributes of selected text. I looked for quite some time for the answer to this question, and finally found it here:

[Attribute String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/AccessingAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000161-SW1)

Some example code. For an NSTextView* named editingView, this gathers an array of NSDictionary objects for all the differently formatted ranges in the selection.

```
NSMutableArray* attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange selRange = editingView.selectedRange;
NSRange effectiveRange = NSMakeRange(selRange.location, 0);
while (NSMaxRange(effectiveRange) < NSMaxRange(selRange)) {
    [attributes addObject: [editingView.textStorage attributesAtIndex: NSMaxRange(effectiveRange) longestEffectiveRange: &effectiveRange inRange: selRange]];
}
```